# ArrayList and LinkedList representation in heap and stack memory in depth

Tags: java, memory, collections

i am trying to understand how both list are represented in heap and stack. As far as i know objects are stored in Heap and references are stored in the stack.

Since the lists are objects it makes sense for them to be stored in the heap, but how are their elements represented(One is of fixed size and the other not)? Does every single element in the collection has a reference in stack or there is one reference pointing only to the collection itself?

Also the LinkedList elements contain more data, i suppose that means more memory will be allocated when storing them, am i right?

I apologize if this question has been asked before, it's just i wasn't able to find an answer to satisfy my questions!

Comment: references are not stored in the stack. ArrayList elements are stored in an array. LinkedList elements are stored inside Node objects referencing each other. In all cases, it's in the heap. Yes, LinkedList is less efficient in terms of memory usage, and basically in terms of everything.

Comment: A "local" reference is created in stack. But an array list is created in heap. A local variable or a local reference or a method is in stack. All others are created in heap. For example, a class variable or reference is also stored in heap. An ArrayList object or LinkedList object is also created in heap as well.

Comment: yes i know that they are stored in the heap, but more indepthly how are elements handled and memory allocated?

Comment: Both are ordinary classes using other ordinary classes or array types. Do you want to know, how object are implemented in general?